Loki configuration Error migratin from otel 0.67.0 to 0.95.0
i'm migratin from the otel 0.67.0 version to the 0.95.0. I changed loki configuration according to:
guide
When i try to deploy otel, i got these errors:
Error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 2 error(s) decoding:

error decoding 'exporters': error reading configuration for "loki": 1 error(s) decoding:

'' has invalid keys: processors

error decoding 'processors': error reading configuration for "transform": 1 error(s) decoding:

'' has invalid keys: logs
2024/05/20 10:21:49 collector server run finished with error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 2 error(s) decoding:

error decoding 'exporters': error reading configuration for "loki": 1 error(s) decoding:

'' has invalid keys: processors

error decoding 'processors': error reading configuration for "transform": 1 error(s) decoding:

'' has invalid keys: logs


Here my configuration:
`
loki:
  endpoint: https://endpoint
  headers:
    authorization: ${EXPORTERS_LOKI_HEADERS_AUTHORIZATION}
  processors:
    attributes:
        actions:
          - action: insert
            key: loki.attribute.labels
            value: container_name, source
            
    resource:
        attributes:
          - action: insert
            key: loki.resource.labels
            value: hostname
          - action: insert
            key: loki.format
            value: json

I tried to follow the guide:
guide
